# Deleting a specific childAdded Firebase Swift 3 iOS10

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, ios10

```
guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {return}
let userRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user_messages").child(uid)
            userRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                let messageId = snapshot.key
                self.messageIdArr.append(messageId)
                print(self.messageIdArr[0])


        userRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "\(messageId)").queryEqual(toValue: "\(self.messageIdArr[0])").ref.removeValue()

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

[image]

Hi guys, So here is my Code and here is a screenie of my Firebase structure. I'm making a snapchat clone.

Here is what I'm trying to do. Under the child `user_messages`. There is a child which contains the currentuser uid and under that are the different ID for the messages. When they view the message, I was the reference to that message be deleted from Firebase under their UID.

so basically, Lets say I want to delete `KcQ7kSELivNWNTAuqck`, How would I do this? My code right now, deletes everything under the UID. I just want to delete 1 messageId not all 5 under `3JEuRBs2U7QbUa7SAgppMmzQUeM2`

Thanks for checking this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

childAdded is called on **each of the values** that exist inside **3JEuRBs2U7QbUa7SAgppMmzQUeM2**.

Meaning that if you call the removeValue inside "childAdded", (like you do now), you will eventually remove all of the ID's.

Solution:
if you know the key for the user message, and the key of the message itself, the only line of code you have to write is this:

```
let messageToDelete = "KcQ7kSELivNWNTAuqck" //You should know how to get that
let userRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user_messages")
.child(uid).child(messageToDelete).removeValue();
```

Comment: I see what you are trying to tell me with your code but I put your code in and it deletes all the `messageId` under that `uid`

Comment: actually, This worked!!!! I just had to pass messageId through MVC and do a whole new reference at all like I did above. Thank you sir!